# React Native - How to extract GPS location from video on Android?

Tags: reactjs, video, gps, native, exif

I am trying to extract location from video metadata in React Native.

Do you guys would have some advices on libraries to use in order to do that ?

I already tried the following libs on real Android device :

- react-native-exif : https://github.com/francisco-sanchez-molina/react-native-exif

  > Works fine for images but i keep getting metadata = "null" for videos
- react-native-media-meta : https://github.com/mybigday/react-native-media-meta

  > Doesnt integrate location data on Android (not tested on IOS)
- react-native-video-metadata : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video-metadata/v/1.0.3

  > Didn't achieved to use this lib properly (seems abandonned tho)

I am running out of options here, so if you have any kind of advice.

Thanks in advance !